# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 14, size is 14 - android

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 14, size is 14
```

This is my log;

```
 01-12 15:09:41.766  19565-19565/com.testapp E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 14, size is 14
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.andtinder.view.CardStackAdapter.getCardModel(CardStackAdapter.java:98)
        at com.andtinder.view.CardStackAdapter.getItem(CardStackAdapter.java:93)
        at com.andtinder.view.CardContainer$GestureListener.onFling(CardContainer.java:458)
        at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:610)
        at com.andtinder.view.CardContainer.onTouchEvent(CardContainer.java:250)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$Inp
```

and this is my cardstackadapter.java line 98 :

```
return mData.get(mData.size() - 1 - position);
```

Comment: it means that position is `-1`

Comment: And what's the value of `mData.size() - 1 - position` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
mData.size() == 14
```

is true if I understood correctly. Still, you try to reference the 14th element. However, the index starts from 0, so the last index of your array having 14 elements is 13. This answers the question of

> "what is the problem?"

You are trying to use the 14th element of an `ArrayList` having 14 elements, while the last index is 13. This throws the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Now, why would this happen?

Let's see this code:

```
return mData.get(mData.size() - 1 - position);
```

Here, the

```
mData.size() - 1 - position
```

part yields 14. Knowing that `mData.size()` is 14, this means that:

> 14 - 1 - position = 14
>
> 13 - position = 14
>
> position = -1

Make sure that you are having the proper value for `position`.